# Django - change select items display

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I use `ModelForm`. One of the fields is:

```
repertoire = models.ForeignKey(Repertoire)
```

I need to change its display type. Instead of using [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str) (or `__unicode__` in Python 2) in display I want to show name and date of repertoire.

How can I do this with `ModelForm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subclass [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and override `label_from_instance` to return the repertoire name and date. Then use the new field in your `ModelForm`.

```
from django import forms

class RepertoireModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s - %s" % (obj.name, obj.date)

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    repertoire = RepertoireModelChoiceField(queryset=Repertoire.objects.all())
```