# ModelForm in Django - select is not populating with appropriate data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I've got a model form in Django that displays nicely - but it's not pulling the appropriate information.

The select dropdowns appear, but are not populated with the options and I am struggling to figure out why.

My models look like this:

```
class Mileage(models.Model):
    start_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='start_locations')
    end_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='end_locations')
    miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.miles

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Trip(models.Model):
    start_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    end_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    trip_date = models.DateTimeField('trip date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

My ModelForm looks like this:

```
class TripsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ['start_location', 'end_location', 'miles', 'trip_date']
        widgets = {
            'start_location': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'start_location'
                }
            ),
            'end_location': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'end_location'
                }
            ),
            'miles': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'id': 'miles',
                    'readonly': 'readonly'
                }
            ),
            'trip_date': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control monthpicker datepicker',
                    'id': 'trip_date'
                }
            ),
        }
```

In my view I'm calling it like this from `view.py`:

```
# Create trip
def trip_create(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TripsForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the form -- will handle this all later
            trip.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = TripsForm()
        # Return to trips with list of date
    return render(request, 'trips/create.html', {'form': form})
```

The 'start_locations' and 'end_locations' selects should be populated with all of locations - currently the selects are totally empty.

I've been looking through documentation: would a `modelformset_factory()` be something to dig into more in this case?

I'm just not sure how to proceed to get it to populate those dropdowns.

Comment: Just to be sure, there are some Locations in the database, right?

Comment: Can you provide your view.py

Comment: Yes @FamousJameous - there are approximately 27 locations in the database.  I will update shortly with the view.py

Comment: You are using a `CharField` for `Trip.start_location` and `Trip.end_location` - that means you'll have to write code to populate the choices. Why not use a foreign key as you do for the `Mileage` model?

Comment: WOW - @Alasdair - that's what I'm missing. I knew it would be something so stupidly simple I should have seen it. I'm almost 100% positive that's the missing link. Please post that as an answer some I can give you the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using a `CharField` for `Trip.start_location` and `Trip.end_location`. If you use a select widget, it's up to you to create the choices to populate it.

If you use a `ForeignKey` for your `start_location` and `end_location` fields, then Django will populate the choices for you.

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    start_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='trip_start_locations')
    end_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='trip_end_locations')
```

After making the change in your models, you'll have to make a migration, then migrate.

Note that I've included `trip` in the `related_name`, since the related name is used to take you from the `Location` model back to `Trip`. You might want to update the `related_name` for your `Mileage` model to include `mileage`.

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there a way I can specify that the dropdowns show the locations `name` instead of the ID of the location?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754776/django-change-select-items-display/6754902#6754902).