# How to display object names on a Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Just Started learning Dango and i got some problems on understanding how to display the name of a object and not it's ID, here I have two tables, one of books and other of i'ts category and in the books table i have a ForeignKey pointing to the category. You can see my codes:

My models.py

```
#class for making the book table on the db
class Books(models.Model):

    ...

    category_cod_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Editora',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
        )

    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Books'

# class for the category tables   
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45
        )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'
```

My forms.py

```
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = [ ... ,'category_cod_category',]
```

The view.py that i'm struggling to understand

```
def book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BooksForm(request.POST or None)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('/show')
            except:
                pass
        else:
            print("form not valid")
    else:
        form = BooksForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

And the Template index.html that should show the category name but it only returns the ID

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/livro">

      {% csrf_token %}

      <!-- not pasting working forms -->

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Books's Category:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.category_cod_category }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

It's displaying a select field with the ID like the picture down bellow, but i want to retrieve it's name (hat to change my code a little bit so you guys cand understand the language, but is the same matter)

[It's displaying a select field with the ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfgwm.png)

Can you guys help me? I've been searcing for answers for some time now and can't find anything that works

For more info: I'm using the last stable version of Both Python and Django

Thanks!

*sorry for any mispronunciation, i'm brazilian and not fluent in english*

Comment: You can set a [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str) method for your `Category` model. This will change the way it is displayed everywhere, including the Django admin. If you only want to change the way it is displayed on the form, then you want a [custom model choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754776/django-change-select-items-display/6754902#6754902).

Comment: Wow! It was soooo simple! Thanks for your answer! Worked like a charm